# TableView error in appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

Am using 3.1.3.GA sdk, Alloys and 2.3.3 Android Emulator. I am using a TableView and whenever it is drawn am getting this error,

```
[ERROR][dalvikvm( 9798)] Could not find class ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.searchview.TiUISearchView', referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUITableView.processProperties
```

**My Code**,

**slidingMenu.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="slidingMenu">
    <TableView id="tableview" className='dataRows' onClick="actionToPerform">
        <TableViewSection id="slidingSection">
            <TableViewRow>
                <ImageView id="option1"/>
                <Label>Option</Label>
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow>
                <ImageView id="option2"/>
                <Label>Option</Label>
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow>
                <ImageView id="option3"/>
                <Label>Option</Label>
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow>
                <ImageView id="option4"/>
                <Label>Option</Label>
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow>
                <ImageView id="option5"/>
                <Label>Option</Label>
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow>
                <ImageView id="option6"/>
                <Label>Option</Label>
            </TableViewRow>
        </TableViewSection>     
    </TableView>
    <View id="closer"></View>
</View>
</Alloy>
```

**slidingMenu.tss**

```
'#SlidingMenu': {
backgroundColor: 'transparent',
width: Ti.UI.FILL,
height: Ti.UI.FILL,
left: 0
},
'TableView': {
    backgroundGradient: {
        type: 'linear',
        startPoint: {x: '0%',y: '0%'},
        endPoint: {x: '0%',y: '100%'},
        colors: [
            {color: '#716E71',offset: '0.0'},
            {color: '#716E72',offset: '1.0'}
        ]
    },  
    width: '70%',
    height: '100%',
    left: 0,
    separatorColor: '#E2E2E2'
},
'TableViewRow': {
    height: '70'
},
'#option1': {
    image: '/images/1.png'
},
'#option2': {
    image: '/images/2.png'
},
'#option3': {
    image: '/images/3.png'
},
'#option4': {
    image: '/images/4.png'
},
'#option5': {
    image: '/images/5.png'
},
'#option6': {
    image: '/images/6.png'
},
'ImageView': {
    left: '5%'
},
'Label': {
    color: '#FFF',  
    left: '20%'
}
'#closer': {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    width: '30%',
    left: '70%'
}
```

**index.xml**

```
<Alloy>
<Window id="search" navBarHidden="true" exitOnClose="true">
    <View>
        <View id="mainView">
            <Require src="views/searcher" id="searcher"></Require>
        </View>
        <View id="slidingView">
            <Require src="views/slidingMenu" id="slidingMenu"></Require>
        </View>
    </View>             
</Window>
</Alloy>
```

I will show TableView when the window is swiped and also tried keeping a button and removed swipe event. I dont know which part of code making the tableview to show this error. Please let know my mistake.

Comment: is there anything in your index.js, searcher.js and slidingmenu.js files?

Comment: Hi Phil, No those are just views and those are probably different from this errors I think so. What is the key for the error being generated in appcel? Am not using searchview inside tableview too. Why this error coming?

Comment: does this one help? https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/155765/alloy-tableview-link-of-class-searchview-failed

Comment: Thank you Phil. But I tried it before itself. Dint worked.